# Matrix Exponentiation in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, matrix

I recently wrote a python code for [matrix exponentiation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matrix-exponentiation/).

Here's the code:

```py
from typing import List
Matrix = List[List[int]]

MOD = 10 ** 9 + 7


def identity(n: int) -> Matrix:
    matrix = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]

    for i in range(n):
        matrix[i][i] = 1

    return matrix


def multiply(mat1: Matrix, mat2: Matrix, copy: Matrix) -> None:
    r1, r2 = len(mat1), len(mat2)
    c1, c2 = len(mat1[0]), len(mat2[0])

    result = [[0] * c2 for _ in range(r1)]

    for i in range(r1):
        for j in range(c2):
            for k in range(r2):
                result[i][j] = (result[i][j] + mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]) % MOD

    for i in range(r1):
        for j in range(c2):
            copy[i][j] = result[i][j]


def power(mat: Matrix, n: int) -> Matrix:
    res = identity(len(mat))

    while n:
        if n & 1:
            multiply(res, mat, res)

        multiply(mat, mat, mat)

        n >>= 1

    return res


def fib(n: int) -> int:
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    magic = [[1, 1],
             [1, 0]]

    mat = power(magic, n - 1)

    return mat[0][0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fib(10 ** 18))
```

I would mainly like to improve this code performance wise, but any comments on style is also much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, but this isn't actually the matrix exponential, it's a matrix power. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: @Bijan Matrix _exponentiation_ is completely different from Matrix _exponential_. Matrix exponentiation is a popular topic in Competitive Programming.

Answer (score 4):

Using the numpy module for numerical computations is often better as the code is generally simpler and much faster. Here is a version adapted to use numpy:

```py
from typing import List
import numpy as np
Matrix = np.matrix

MOD = 10 ** 9 + 7


def power(mat: Matrix, n: int) -> Matrix:
    res = np.identity(len(mat), dtype=np.int64)

    while n:
        if n & 1:
            np.matmul(res, mat, out=res)
            res %= MOD

        np.matmul(mat, mat, out=mat)
        mat %= MOD # Required for numpy if you want correct results
        n >>= 1

    return res


def fib(n: int) -> int:
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    magic = np.matrix([[1, 1], [1, 0]], dtype=np.int64)
    mat = power(magic, n - 1)
    return mat[0,0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fib(10 ** 18))
```

As you can see, using numpy reduce significantly the size of the code since it provide primitive for creating and computing matrices (eg. matrix multiplication).
Numpy is also faster since it uses fast native code to perform the computations. However, here, your matrices are too small so that numpy can provide any speed-up.
Also note that numpy as a downside: it does not support large integers as python does. So, the code above works well as long as you do not increase too much the value of `MOD`. You can use `dtype=object` to force numpy to support large integers but it will be slower (especially on bigger matrices).

Besides using numpy, you can also specialize your code to compute 2x2 matrices much faster in this specific case. Here is the result:

```py
from typing import List
Matrix = List[List[int]]

MOD = 10 ** 9 + 7


def identity_2x2() -> Matrix:
    return [1, 0, 0, 1]


def multiply_2x2(mat1: Matrix, mat2: Matrix, copy: Matrix) -> None:
    a00, a01, a10, a11 = mat1
    b00, b01, b10, b11 = mat2

    copy[0] = (a00 * b00 + a01 * b10) % MOD
    copy[1] = (a00 * b01 + a01 * b11) % MOD
    copy[2] = (a10 * b00 + a11 * b10) % MOD
    copy[3] = (a10 * b01 + a11 * b11) % MOD


def power_2x2(mat: Matrix, n: int) -> Matrix:
    res = identity_2x2()

    while n:
        if n & 1:
            multiply_2x2(res, mat, res)

        multiply_2x2(mat, mat, mat)

        n >>= 1

    return res


def fib(n: int) -> int:
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    magic = [1, 1, 1, 0]
    mat = power_2x2(magic, n - 1)
    return mat[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fib(10 ** 18))
```

This is faster because the default interpreter (CPython) executes loops very slowly, so it is better to avoid them as much as possible. It is also faster because no additional list is created.

Please note that if you want your code to run faster, you could use the [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) interpreter.

Comment: Great answer! But why does the first code output `0`? Also, I'm using this as a template for matrix exponentiation problems in general, so the code has to be flexible!

Comment: It does not return `0` on my machine, neither on an [online python IDE](https://repl.it/languages/python3). Maybe you are running on a 32 bits system where np.int64 are not supported? Try to test with smaller inputs to see if this is due to an integer overflow.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have a 32-bit system and the code does work for smaller values. Is there any way I can make it work on a 32-bit system? Thanks!

Comment: I just discover that can use `dtype=object` as a fallback solution to solve this but note that it could be much slower (although probably not more that if it was done in pure python).

Comment: It shows `TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported` when I run it. Full error: https://hastebin.com/inuxureyoz.txt

Comment: Wow, that quite surprising. Which version of python do you have?

Comment: The version I have is 3.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105055/discussion-between-srivaths-and-jerome-richard).